# Using functions with the same name in different classes

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use functions with the same name that work differently in different classes?
The `Polynomial` and `Rational` are discrete classes (not inherited):

```
class Polynomial{
public:
   double evaluateAt(double x);
};

class Rational{
public:
   double evaluateAt(double x);
};
```

Comment: Try compiling the code. Experiment! :-)

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. If the methods do different things, give them different names or you'll just end up with confusion down the line.

Comment: Different scopes, so yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the methods are in the scope of their classes.

Comment: Is it namespace or scope?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just try it in an IDE.

In fact, in compiler's eyes, they are not the same. You could treat class name as a name prefix, like Polynimial_evaluate(...) and Rational_evaluate(...). Note this is just a way to look at the codes, the real details are not like this, but familiar.